# How to create GridModel with nested objects? (QML Qt)

Tags: qt, qml

I have a cell object. And i need to create a Model including these cells.

Here's cell code. The Model must contain at least 20 cells?

```
Rectangle {
    width: 270
    height: 277
    color: "#333333"
    radius: 8

    Rectangle {
        z: 10
        height: 32
        width: 77
        color: "#333333"
        radius: 8
        y: 8
        x: 8

        Button {
            height: 32
            width: 77
            background: btnColor1
        }

        Text {
            text: "DMT 10"
            color: "white"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    Item {
        height: 154
        width: 270

        Image {
            source: "qrc:/images/cellimage.png"
            id: imageOriginal
            visible: false
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangleMask
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: 8
            visible: false
        }

        OpacityMask {
            id: opacityMask
            anchors.fill: imageOriginal
            source: imageOriginal
            maskSource: rectangleMask
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        y: 149
        width: 270
        height: 120
        color: '#333333'

        ColumnLayout {
            x: 17
            y: 15
            spacing: 8

            Item {
                height: 17

                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/person.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }

                Text {
                    text: "Cерийный номер:"
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }

            Item {
                height: 17

                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/baterry.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }

                Text {
                    text: "Заряд: 63%"
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }

            Item {
                height: 17

                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/file.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }

                Text {
                    text: "Файлы: 100%"
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, I declare a `ListModel` which has an `objid` parameter. I also declare a `sampleData` object where the same `objid` can be used as a key to access additional meta data.

```
    ListModel {
        id: sampleModel
        ListElement { objid: "obj1" }
        ListElement { objid: "obj2" }
        ListElement { objid: "obj3" }
    }

    property var sampleData: ({
        "obj1": { "bat": "63%", "fil": "100%" },
        "obj2": { "bat": "60%", "fil": "90%" },
        "obj3": { "bat": "59%", "fil": "80%" }
    })
```

To access the nested data in the delegate, I use:

```
    sampleData[objid].bat
    sampleData[objid].fil
```

The following has a small edit to your original delegate to show the nested metadata access and also includes the test GridView application.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    GridView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: sampleModel
        cellWidth: 300
        cellHeight: 300
        delegate: MyGridCell {
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: sampleModel
        ListElement { objid: "obj1" }
        ListElement { objid: "obj2" }
        ListElement { objid: "obj3" }
    }

    property var sampleData: ({
        "obj1": { "bat": "63%", "fil": "100%" },
        "obj2": { "bat": "60%", "fil": "90%" },
        "obj3": { "bat": "59%", "fil": "80%" }
    })
}

// MyGridCell.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Rectangle{
    width: 270
    height: 277
    color: "#333333"
    radius: 8
    Rectangle{
        z: 10
        height: 32
        width: 77
        color: "#333333"
        radius: 8
        y:8
        x:8
        Button{
            height: 32
            width: 77
            background: btnColor1
        }
        Text{
            text: "DMT 10"
            color: "white"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
    Item{
        height: 154
        width: 270
        Image{
            source: "qrc:/images/cellimage.png"
            id: imageOriginal
            visible: false
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rectangleMask
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: 8
            visible: false
        }
        OpacityMask {
            id: opacityMask
            anchors.fill: imageOriginal
            source: imageOriginal
            maskSource: rectangleMask
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        y: 149
        width: 270
        height: 120
        color: '#333333'
        ColumnLayout{
            x: 17
            y: 15
            spacing: 8
            Item {
                height: 17
                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/person.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                Text {
                    text: "Cерийный номер:"
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }
            Item {
                height: 17
                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/baterry.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                Text {
                    text: "Заряд: %1".arg(sampleData[objid].bat)
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }
            Item {
                height: 17
                Image {
                    source: "qrc:/images/file.svg"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                Text {
                    text: "Файлы: %1".arg(sampleData[objid].fil)
                    color: "white"
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    leftPadding: 21
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Hi again. How to create a scrollbar for this model?

Comment: Updated GridView to show ScrollBar, but, in the future, please use a new question instead of changing the scope of an existing question.